# c# mysql command parameters addwithvalue truncates input value

Tags: c#, mysql

I have this case, where I update a mySql db table using c#.
The field updated is varchar(10).
The problem is that if a value more than 10 characters is passed, then the value written is truncated, but with no exception.
Is that normal? Am I missing something?

The code below shows this happening

```
string query = @"update params set paramvalue=@val where paramid='aParam'; 
    select paramvalue from params where paramid='aParam';";
MySqlConnection connection =
  new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;user=root;database=world;port=3306;password=******;");
connection.Open();
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);

string myVal = "123456789012345";

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val", myVal);

string theirVal = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
Console.WriteLine(theirVal); // this outputs "1234567890"
```

**UPDATE:**
The exact same command returns a warning on execution in workbech client!

> 1 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s): 1265 Data truncated for column 'ParamValue' at row 1 Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 1    0.000 sec

Could I utilize these warning in the mySql client in my code?
Any suggestion? I cant find the way...

Comment: Yes this is correct behavior

Comment: Yes this is normal. `varchar(10)` is a field that is only 10 characters long. Anything longer than that will be truncated

Comment: I wouldn't say it's correct behavior, more like it's expected behavior since MySQL doesn't care to give an error when truncation would happen by default, like so many other things.

Comment: Thats my point, since, I think SQLServer throws exception for similar case...

Comment: it wont throw any exception since its a store Query it will only store in the length possible

Comment: I updated my question, as I see there is execution warnings in mySQL workbench

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-tracing-mysql.html

Use this as a reference: MySqlTrace.Listeners.Add(new ConsoleTraceListener()); and maybe write your own to catch the warnings you want..

But I think your domain should handle the 'warning/error': don't give  the database invalid data.

Comment: Thank you Bert! This might prove rather useful in my case. I agree with what you recommend about not passing invalid data, but in my case that is done by.. "other people", who ... tend to misuse the application, so I try to be safe from them :)

Comment: maybe the problem is with the way the app is written